# Generating Weblogo image using Java

Tags: java, image, java-2d, java-3d

Currently I am working on [Weblogo](http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/). I need to generate [weblogo image](http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/img/cap_hth.png) using Java language. So in this image, each column will contain number of alphabet characters. Height of the characters may vary within column. Width of all column will remain same irrespective of height of column.
    From weblogo image you can see that, I need to change the height of character without changing its width. Also I need to concatenate all these column of variable height. How should I implement this? What should be the best technique or API that I should follow? 
   Output need not be an image. It can be in java applet or swing. I need to make it interactive as well.  e.g. If user clicks a particular character, an event should be generated indicating the column number and character that generated this event.

(P.S. My program will have alphabet characters (in ASCII or UNICODE) and their position on X axis as a input.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. I am using JPanel to draw weblogo. I used drawString method of Graphics2D object to draw single character.
    I used AffineTransform to scale character horizontally as well as vertically as per the requirement. Rest of the things are trivial. I have hosted code on Google Code site.

http://code.google.com/p/nested-weblogo/

Code is very trivial and will require knowledge of basic swing components and weblogo.